# Magento 2 setup:upgrade giving error

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

I have installed Magento 2 on my ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine and when I created a new module and tried to do setup:upgrade after enabling it, it shows following error.

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/html/Magento# php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Composer
/var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Magento
/var/www/html/Magento/var/generation/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/html/Magento/var/di/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Itdeation_Catalog':
Schema post-updates:
Module 'Itdeation_Catalog':
Data install/update:
Module 'Itdeation_Catalog':
Installing data... PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapperInterface in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73

Fatal error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Setup\PropertyMapperInterface in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 73
```

Please help!

Comment: you have issue inside Itdeation_Catalog module, please check your setup folder installschema.php file

Answer (score 5):

First you can use this command for compiling di

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

After finish of compilation if not getting any error delete di folder from /var/www/html/Magento/var/ and then run setup upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

1.This is interface problem mean that in `namespace\modulename\Api\Data\yourInterface` should have some problems.

2.When your module try to install data mean when InstallData.php run which is connected through your model and [yourModel] is connected with [yourInterface] so you need to debug these files.

3.As you listed your error is showing :- Installing data... PHP Fatal error so you need to figure out three file first
 
1.Api
2.Model
3.InstallData.php

Make sure you have added these two namespaces in your model.

```
use namespace\yourModule\Model\yourModelName;
use namespace\yourModule\Model\yourModelNameFactory;
```

If you still face any problem then let me know I will try to solve it.